# How to remove margin from last li, in pure CSS with IE 6 support?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

In this condition is it possible to not to apply `margin-right` to last `li`.

I need pure css way and support in IE6 and 7 also and without changing **HTML**. is there any way to achieve this.

```
ul li {display:inline;margin-right:10px}

<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Aliquam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Morbi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Praesent</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nowhere" >Pellentesque</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use IE CSS expressions to achieve this.

```
ul#nav li {
    margin-right: 10px;
    /* for IE only: */
    margin-right: expression(this.nextSibling == null ? '0' : '10px' );
}

/* for standards browsers: */
ul#nav li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Tested and it works in IE7. I don't have access to IE6 but it should work the same.

If possible, it would be best to put the expression rule in an IE-only stylesheet.

Comment: in place of expression i would like to use javascript

Comment: Why? You asked for a pure CSS solution, that's what you got.

Comment: will expression work without javascript? and why i do not prefer expression see here http://developer.yahoo.net/blog/archives/2007/07/high_performanc_6.html

Comment: Well sorry but you can't support ancient relics like IE6 without some compromise. One expression wouldn't make a massive difference and it doesn't apply to IE8, Firefox and other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a negative bottom margin on the  tag.  I don't even know if that would work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: `margin-bottom: -10px;` where 10px is the size of the margin on the `li`.

Comment: You'd want to do that with the IE 6 hack or in an IE 6 specific style sheet of course.

Answer (score 0):

Give the last `<li>` a class and then apply `margin-right: 0px` to the class.

There is a [`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo) pseudo class in CSS3 but won't work in IE 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd advise using the `:last-child` selector, but IE 6 and 7 do not support this.

You could add a class to the last `li` element and apply a style like `margin-right: 0` to it.

Without changing the HTML, I'm not aware of any *pure css* way to make that work in IE 6 or 7.